# Is it possible to have a method input be one of two possible Classes in Java?

Tags: java, class, class-method

I have two classes, `Foo1` and `Foo2` that are not hierarchically related, so an instance of `Foo1` is not an instance of `Foo2` nor conversely.

In a different class from these, I have a method `doStuffWithFoo` that ideally should take either `Foo1` or `Foo2` as input, and then behave accordingly. Here's the basic idea that I'm after:

```
private double[] doStuffWithFoo(Fooi foo, Bar bar1, Bar bar2, double fortyTwo) {
    Fooi changingFoo = foo;
    double[] fooBars = new double[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        double[] array = getArrayFromFoo(foo,bar1,fortyTwo);
        double fooBar = getDoubleFromArray(array);
        fooBars[i] = fooBar;
        foo = foo.getNextFoo();
    }
    return fooBars;
}
```

where I've written two very different methods

```
private double[] getArrayFromFoo(Foo1 foo, Bar bar, double fortyTwo)
private double[] getArrayFromFoo(Foo2 foo, Bar bar, double fortyTwo)
```

and each `Foo` class implements its own `getNextFoo()` method that returns the same type of `Foo` that it takes in.

The method `getArrayFromFoo` doesn't really have anything to do with the `Foo` classes and it takes input from the class where this method lives, so it doesn't make sense to create a common interface for the `Foo`s.

The ways I see to handle the situation are:

1. Make `doStuffWithFoo` take a generic object as input, then check whether the class is `Foo1`, `Foo2`, or something else. The problem with this approach is that I strongly prefer compile time errors to run time errors.
2. Write two versions of `doStuffWithFoo` just as I wrote two versions of `getArrayFromFoo`. The problem with this approach is that I'll be duplicating a large amount of code which may cause inconsistencies when the code is changed at some point down the line.

Is there any other option? The ideal solution I have in mind is if there is a way to declare the input type to be `Foo1` or `Foo2`, which is like approach 1 but with instant errors. Is there a way to do this in Java?

Comment: Why don't you have both Foo1 and Foo2 implement an interface called Foo, with a method getArrayFromFoo() that returns a double[]?

Comment: Sometimes the java object model is difficult to work with and insn't always obvious.  The two answers here are the two you generally expect to avoid duplication.  The third is that `doStuffWithFoo` should not accept Foo1 or Foo2 at all but take the array as an argument, and `getArrayFromFoo` should be called by the methods which call `doStuffWithFoo`. This can cause some duplication, but there really is no other *good* option that the two below or this one.

Comment: @couling getArrayFromFoo is actually called inside a for loop, making that difficult to implement.

Comment: your two options are below then.  personally I'd go with the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
private double[] doStuffWithFoo(Foo1 foo) {
    double[] array = getArrayFromFoo1(foo);
    doCommonStuff(array);
    return array;
}


private double[] doStuffWithFoo(Foo2 foo) {
    double[] array = getArrayFromFoo2(foo);
    doCommonStuff(array);
    return array;
}

private void doCommonStuff(double[] array) {
    // common stuff
}
```

Comment: I suppose there isn't a better way in my case since an interface for `Foo1` and `Foo2` doesn't make sense. This still creates a fair amount of repeated code, but I think it's the best I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try defining an interface:

```
public interface HasDoubleArray {

   public double[] getDoubleArray();
}
```

Then have each `Foo1` and `Foo2` implement this interface, overriding the method `getDoubleArray()` to return a `double[]` in their own special way. You could then call it in your directing code:

```
private double[] doStuffWithFoo(HasDoubleArray hda) {
   double[] array = hda.getDoubleArray();
   // DO STUFF WITH array
   return array;
}
```

Comment: A good idea, but `getArrayFromFoo` actually takes other inputs, not just `foo`, and has more to do with the class where the method is written. I'll update my question to make that clear. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @PengOne - Hmm, interesting. I see you also ruled out Ted's answer :\ I need to go offline now but I'll update my answer to try and help when I get a chance. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I updated the code snippet with more details of how I'm using these methods. If you happen to take another look at this, I'd be grateful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have some larger design and factoring issue going on here, given the response you've given to the "use an interface" answer that you've given to Kublai Khan, and this remark you've made:

> The method getArrayFromFoo doesn't really have anything to do with the Foo classes and it takes input from the class where this method lives, so it doesn't make sense to create a common interface for the Foos.

If this is truly so, why would `getArrayFromFoo` even need to take a Foo1 or Foo2 as an argument?  Well, it sounds like you want to dispatch on the type (i.e., do something different depending on whether you got a Foo1 or a Foo2)—but then why wouldn't you do this by delegating the responsibility for doing to type-appropriate thing to the types in question?

I understand the desire not to put logic in Foo1 and Foo2 that pertains to things that properly belong in the class that implements `getArrayFromFoo`, but there are other ways around that—e.g., use the Visitor Pattern to so that Foo1 and Foo2 call you back with the appropriate thing to do.

Also, the concern that you have with code duplication raises even more red flags here—even if you do end up having to write methods specific for Foo1 and Foo2, why wouldn't you be able to factor out the duplicate parts into a common method?

```
public interface FooVisitor<T> {
    public T visitFoo1(Foo1 foo1);
    public T visitFoo2(Foo2 foo2);
}

public interface Foo {
    public <T> T accept(FooVisitor<T> visitor);
}

public class Foo1 implements Foo {

    // ...

    public <T> T accept(FooVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitFoo1(this);
    }

    // ...

}

public class Foo2 implements Foo {

    // ...

    public <T> T accept(FooVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitFoo2(this);
    }

    // ...

}

public class ClientClass implements FooVisitor<Quux> {

    // ...

    private double[] doStuffWithFoo(Foo foo, Bar bar1, Bar bar2, double fortyTwo) {
        // do common stuff...

        // Now do the type-specific part
        Quux whatever = foo.visit(this);
    }

    public Quux visitFoo1(Foo1 foo1) {
        // do Foo1-specific stuff
    }

    public Quux visitFoo2(Foo2 foo1) {
        // do Foo2-specific stuff
    }

    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think reason of your problem is parameters that you dont do validation:

```
private static void doStuffWithFoo(Fooz foo, Bar b, double d) {
        Double fortyTwo;
        Bar bar;
        if(!foo.b().equals(b)||foo.d()!=d)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

For this I would follow Kublai Khan way to use one interface as parameter. Also I think you dont need 2xBar parameter. If parameters can not pass the test then I would throw (lets say) IllegalArgumentException.You said getArrayFromFoo does nothing with the classes so you can pass parameters to this method after validation? (if bar and double is not instance of foo (or no logic) so I think JVM can not know what belongs to what)

```
class Foo implements Fooz{

    @Override
    public double d() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Double(41);
    }

    @Override
    public Bar b() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Bar(41);
    }

}
class Foo2 implements Fooz{

    public double d() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Double(42);
    }

    @Override
    public Bar b() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Bar(42);
    }



}

class Bar{
    Bar(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int x;
}

interface Fooz{
    double d();
    Bar b();

}

public class CompareFoos{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo2 foo2 = new Foo2();
        //doStuffWithFoo(foo2, foo2.b(), foo2.d());
        doStuffWithFoo(foo2, foo.b(), foo2.d());

    }

    private static void doStuffWithFoo(Fooz foo, Bar b, double d) {
        Double fortyTwo;
        Bar bar;
        //foo creates new bar for each call thats why i didnt use !foo.b().equals(b)
        if(foo.b().x!=b.x||foo.d()!=d)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        fortyTwo = d;
        bar = b;
        System.out.println(foo.getClass().getName() + " " + d + " " + b.x);
        private double[] getArrayFromFoo(foo, bar, fortyTwo)
        //more code here...

    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I want compile time errors rather than run time errors. For reasons I tried to explain in response to Kublai, it doesn't make sense for my purposes to create an interface for `Foo1` and `Foo2`.